# ISOWeek2Date R output the first day of the week?

Tags: r, datetime, time, iso

Quick question.

The IsoWeek2Date function in the ISOweek package in R takes an ISOweek formatted string and outputs a date.

This is probably the case, but I just need to confirm...

Is this date the first day of the week?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and test it?

Comment: Good point... It does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it looks like it outputs the first day of the week...